# How to expand a polygon to reach a nearby line

Tags: postgis

I would like to expand a polygon so that it fills an empty space between itself and a nearby (and touching in two points) line, as in [the image posted here](http://cl.ly/image/3F0W3l0b0Y3r).  As you can see the blue linestring makes an empty space on top of the pink polygon and I want to fill it with the polygon.  Is there a postgis solution to this ?  I havent' found any "easy" way.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is similar to the one I presented [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60655/polygon-to-fill-gap/60672#60672). Only in this case you need to buff up the linestring a bit.

```
WITH p AS (
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,1 1, 0 1, 0 0)')) as geo
),
l AS (
SELECT ST_BUFFER(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0.0 0.0,0.5 0, 0.7 -1, 1 0)'),0.000000000000001) as geo
),
bigpoly AS(
SELECT ST_UNION(geo) as geom
FROM(
    SELECT geo FROM p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT geo FROM l) as q
)
SELECT ST_BUFFER(ST_BuildArea(ST_InteriorRingN(geom,i)),0.000000000000001) as geo
FROM bigpoly
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,(SELECT ST_NumInteriorRings(geom) FROM bigpoly)) as i
```

This will give you the missing piece, now you just need to ST_UNION it with the rest, you might also want to check if it's really a correct one if your original polygon contains holes.

Comment: Thank you very much Jakub.
This is very informative and helpful.
Didier